# php password functions not working

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

In my website there's a chance to make a user and sign in. I wanted to use PHP's new password functions `password_hash` and `password_verify` for better security. In my own computer, I've PHP 5.5, so the functions work fine. However, in my webhotel, there is a PHP with version 5.2, so I had to download password functions from [Github](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php). Now the functions don't work. Looks like `password_hash` returns nothing, because I've nothing in database after signup.

I've checked error log and it has nothing about this in. And yes, I have `error_reporting` on `E_ALL | E_STRICT`, `log_errors` on and I'm looking at the right file.

I repeat myself: Functions work without any problems as hardcoded in my computer (PHP 5.5) but don't work as downloaded (PHP 5.2).

My code:

```
// model:
public function getUser($email, $pass) {
    $this->search("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", array($email));
    if($this->countRows() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $row = $this->fetchRow();
    if(!password_verify($pass, $row["password"])) {
        return false;
    }
    if(password_needs_rehash($row["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
        $this->run("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?",array(password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT),$row["id"]));
    }
    return $row;
}

public function userExists($email) {
    $this->search("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", array($email));
    if($this->countRows() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// sign up
public function reg() {
    if($this->model->userExists($_POST["email"])) {
        header("Location: " . PUBLICROOT . "/index/index/error/emailAlreadyExists");
        die();
    }
    $this->model->run("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, birthday) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", 
            array($_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"],$_POST["email"],
                password_hash($_POST["password"],PASSWORD_DEFAULT),$_POST["birthday"]."-".$_POST["birthmonth"]."-".$_POST["birthyear"]));
    $this->in();
}

// sign in
public function in() {
    $u = $this->model->getUser($_POST["email"],$_POST["password"]);
    if($u === false) {
        header("Location: " . PUBLICROOT . "/index/index/error/signInFailed");
        die();
    } else {
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $u["id"];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
        $_SESSION["firstname"] = $u["firstname"];
        $_SESSION["lastname"] = $u["lastname"];
        $_SESSION["time"] = time();
        header("Location: " . PUBLICROOT . "/home/index");
        die();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ***This library requires PHP >= 5.3.7 OR a version that has the $2y fix backported into it (such as RedHat provides).*** 5.2 is *sooo* not supported by this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to [read the README](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

> **This library requires PHP >= 5.3.7** OR a version that has the $2y fix backported into it (such as RedHat provides).

Comment: Dammit, didn't see that. Any suggestions? I don't want to use md5.

Comment: `password_hash` is simply a wrapper for [crypt](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), which is available to all version of PHP5

Comment: ...with the caveat that PHP versions before 5.3.7 contain a bug in crypt which substantially weakens passwords hashed with it, which is why the version restriction exists. Use are your own risk, @user3725053.

Answer (score 2):

- PHP 5.5 offers the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which uses the BCrypt algorithm.
- With PHP 5.3.7 you can use the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).
- Since PHP 5.3 it is possible to use BCrypt (algorithm "2a" instead of "2y")
- Earlier PHP versions do not support BCrypt, you best bet is probably the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library, though they also have a fallback to a less safe algorithm. Maybe you can find an extension which you can install on your server with BCrypt support.